# What are the current challenges developers face in creating a dapp in ethereum?

Tags: truffle, dapp-development, dapps, truffle-deployment, embark

Can you tell  what are the pain points for the Blockchain developers while developing DApp/ managing consortium networks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think DApp is a challenge because in the end it is just an application and you can face general problems that you face writing any application.

Most of the complex part is handled by the Web3.js library (given you are using JS/NodeJS to write your code) and similarly other libraries to handle the JSON-RPC communication. The documentation and support for web3 is tremendous compared to other libraries.

When you start out you can face few challenges in communicating with your smart contract because the documentation can be confusing sometimes. The only place I faced challenges were listening to events on Ethereum and had to play around with various filters on those events to get the right fit ( I am still in the process of learning that, pretty ambiguous)

If you are writing the chaincode (smart contracts) then getting along with Solidity might take sometime because there are many challenges you face when you deal with structures and it keeps on getting more and more complex. Main reason for that is many things that you do in your traditional programming languages, do not work here. E.g working with literals or assigning some runtime variables.

If you understand these things properly I don't think there should be a problem. Don't be afraid to play around.